# Putting text on top of image not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, text

I am trying to overlay text onto the image and cannot figure out how too. This may be an easy question so if you can go into some detail on how it is done that would be much appreciated.

```js
import React from "react";
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import topImg from "/Users/rayhewitt/Desktop/react-portfolio/src/imgs/topImg.jpeg";
import useStyles from "./HeadStyles";

const Head = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div className={classes.top}>
      <img className={classes.image} src={topImg} alt="codingPic" />
      <Typography className={classes.intro} align="center">
        Hey, im Ray Hewitt a UI/UX frontend developer
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Head;
```

```css
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export default makeStyles({
  top: {
backgroundColor: "rgba(8,89,145,255)",
height: "5000px",
  },
  image: {
paddingTop: "48px",
width: "100%",
zIndex: "100",
  },
  intro: {
justifyContent: "center",
position: "absolute",
zIndex: "101",
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickly looking at your code it seems like you're almost there.  I think the only thing missing is a `position: relative` on your parent container and a position on the text.

```
.top {
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; // or left/right/bottom
}
```

That should do it.

What's important to understand here is that if you `position: absolute` an element then it will stick to whatever parent throughout the tree is `position: relative` or it will stick to body if there isn't any.  Marking the parent container as `position: relative` will have the text stick to that parent, then you can control the positioning with top/bottom/left/right.

Side note, I'm not sure it makes sense to use `justify-content` if the text isn't `display: flex`.

Comment: Thank you this was very insightful. I did think I was getting close. and the justify content was just a attempt I removed it just after posting this question. Great explanation